# NPM install bootstrap 4 not working with JS files

Tags: node.js, express, npm, bootstrap-4

I have installed bootstrap with NPM and got the css to work fine with the following syntax:

```
//server side 
const path = require('path');
expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')));

//client side 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
```

However, when I try to do the same thing for adding the js from bootstrap 4 I'm not able to success. I have tried the following way:

```
expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')));

<script src="bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me out with this one? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? Is that the right path?

Comment: Yeah should be the right path. Simply does not connect to the bootstrap JS library. Not error msg or anything.

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean *what evidence do you have* that it doesn't "connect"? Either it's the right path or it isn't. There's not much more to go wrong. Is the code in the page or isn't it?

Comment: When I try to run some bootstrap templating that requires the JS lib and it does not react.